# Extract lower triangle portion of a matrix

Tags: matrix, julia

I was wondering if there is a command or a package in Julia that permits us to extract directly the lower triangle portion of a matrix, excluding the diagonal. I can call R commands for that (like lowerTriangle of the gdata package), obviously, but I'd like to know if Julia has something similar. For example, imagine I have the matrix

```
1.0    0.751   0.734    
0.751   1.0    0.948    
0.734  0.948    1.0
```

I don't want to create a lower triangular matrix like

```
NA     NA      NA     
0.751   NA      NA    
0.734  0.948    NA
```

but extract the lower portion of the matrix as an array: `0.751 0.734  0.948`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Lower triangular matrix in julia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39039553/lower-triangular-matrix-in-julia)

Comment: No, my question is different. I'll do changes in my question, then.

Comment: For those voting to close this as duplicate: this question is at best the inverse of the other one, but really they're quite different questions with different requirements. Don't let a few common words in the title fool you.

Comment: Yeah sorry.... Tried to find suggestive keywords and a suitable title

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're OK with creating a lower triangular matrix as an intermediate step, you can use logical indexing and `tril!` with an extra argument to get what you need.

```
julia> M = [1.0 0.751 0.734
0.751 1.0 0.948
0.734 0.948 1.0];
julia> v = M[tril!(trues(size(M)), -1)]
3-element Array{Float64, 1}:
0.751
0.734
0.948
```

The `trues` call returns an array of M's shape filled with boolean `true` values. `tril!` then prunes this down to just the part of the matrix that we want. The second argument to tril! tells it which superdiagonal to start from, which we use here to avoid the values in the leading diagonal.

We use the result of that for indexing into M, and that returns an array with the required values.

Comment: This only works, though, if you don't mind throwing away those zeros that appear in the lower triangular part.  You can use the same idea with a logical array instead to be a bit safer and more efficient: `M[tril!(trues(size(M)), -1)]`

Comment: That's a good point. I'll update the answer with your solution in a moment, thank you.

Comment: It would be nice to avoid this intermediate allocation though. This issue is also very common with symmetric distance matrices, and there are many people wanting an allocation-free solution.

Comment: This solution seems ok guys, thank you! It is not code demanding, it is simple and quick

Answer (score 3):

Using [comprehensions](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v0.6.3/manual/arrays/#Comprehensions-1):

```
julia> [M[m, n] for m in 2:size(M, 1) for n in 1:m-1]
3-element Array{Float64,1}:
 0.751
 0.734
 0.948
```

But it is *much slower* than the sundar/Matt B. solution:

```
lower_triangular_1(M) = [M[m, n] for m in 2:size(M, 1) for n in 1:m-1]
lower_triangular_2(M) = [M[m, n] for n in 1:size(M, 2) for m in n+1:size(M, 1)]
lower_triangular_3(M) = M[tril!(trues(size(M)), -1)]
using BenchmarkTools
using LinearAlgebra  # avoid warning in 0.7

M=rand(100, 100)
```

Testing with Julia Version `0.7.0-alpha.0`:

```
julia> @btime lower_triangular_1(M);
  73.179 μs (10115 allocations: 444.34 KiB)

julia> @btime lower_triangular_2(M);
  71.157 μs (10117 allocations: 444.41 KiB)

julia> @btime lower_triangular_3(M);
  16.325 μs (6 allocations: 40.19 KiB)
```

Not elegant, but faster (with `@views`):

```
function lower_triangular_4(M)
    # works only for square matrices
    res = similar(M, ((size(M, 1)-1) * size(M, 2)) ÷ 2)
    start_idx = 1
    for n = 1:size(M, 2)-1
        @views column = M[n+1:end, n]
        last_idx = start_idx -1 + length(column)
        @views res[start_idx:last_idx] = column[:]
        start_idx = last_idx + 1
    end
end

julia> @btime lower_triangular_4(M);
  4.272 μs (101 allocations: 44.95 KiB)
```

Comment: A nice approach too! I'm trying to avoid loops by the way, but thank you!